# Java Save Class Not Saving

Tags: java, file, libgdx, save

Sorry if this was asked before, but I either can't find it, or can't understand the solutions that people way more smater than me gave.

So, I have a libgdx game that need the functionality of game saves. I decided to go through the route of storing all of my game data into a GameData class, with a bunch of random static variable to be saved into files with the .sav files.

Here is the GameData Class:

```
package Game;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class GameData implements Serializable
{
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1;

  public static String name;
  public static String currentWeapon;

  public static void init()
  {
     name = "";
     currentWeapon = "";
  }
}
```

I use a class called Loadevas, with the static method save(int id), load(int id), delete(int id), and saveFileExists(int id), each doing what they are named after. Here it is:

```
public class Loadevas 
{
    public static GameData gd;

    public static void save(int id)
    {
        try{
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(
                    new FileOutputStream("save" + id + ".sav"));
            out.writeObject(gd);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Gdx.app.exit();
        }
    }

    public static void load(int id)
    {
        try{
            if(saveFileExists(id))
            {
                ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(
                        new FileInputStream("save" + id + ".sav"));
                gd = (GameData) in.readObject();
                in.close();
            }
         }catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Gdx.app.exit();
        }
    }

    public static void delete(int id)
    {
        try{
            if(saveFileExists(id))
            {
                File f = new File("save" + id + ".sav");
                f.delete();
            }
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Gdx.app.exit();
        }
    }

    public static boolean saveFileExists(int id)
    {
        File f = new File("save" + id + ".sav");
        return f.exists();
    }
 }
```

Right now, it will save the game data to a save(whatever number).sav file, but it will not track any changes made to the GameData. Example was that when I set the name String to "derp" and print it, it will print derp. However, when I saved it, closed the game, reboot it, load the save, and start printing, it will print out null, which isnt even the starting value, so I am very confused.

Any help would be appreciated, and thanks in advance!

-Hummus

Comment: static fields are not serialized in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Static Variables are not serialized, So during deserialization static variable value will loaded from the class.

So when load data you got null in variable because at that time class variable are null(Current value will be loaded).